Unity WebGl Firebase: Request Failed![0] when loading data
I have a function that downloads and shows data stored in a JSON file from Firebase.
It downloads data from a company, so the user fills in a pincode and then it downloads the data from that company.
I tested this in Unity and it works like it should, it also works on webgl.
However there is one company that is quite large and has a lot of data, again in Unity it works without any problems, it loads and shows the data.
But on Webgl I get the error "Request Failed![0]" 2 times, 1 at around 60% and 1 at around 90%.
There are no "CORS" errors and I also tried increasing the timeout but with no results.
I suspect it has something to do with the size of the data, but I am not sure.
I tested on multiple different browsers as well with no result.
here is the part of code that downloads the data:

public static void GetCompanyReport(UnityAction<ReportRequest> callback = null)
{
    AuthHandler.GetIdToken(tokenCallback =>
    {
        if (tokenCallback.IsSuccess)
        {
            HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(new System.Uri(FirebaseConfig.Instance.DatabaseURL + @"/Test/TestData"), HTTPMethods.Post, (req, response) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Reached Code in GetCompanyReport Block 1");
                if (response.IsSuccess)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Reached Code in GetCompanyReport Block 2");

                    Debug.Log("Reached Code in GetCompanyReport Block 3");
                    ReportRequest resp = JsonUtility.FromJson<ReportRequest>(response.DataAsText);
                    Debug.Log("Request Finished! Text received: " + response.DataAsText);
                    resp.IsSuccess = true;
                    callback?.Invoke(resp);
                }
                else
                {
                    bool keepGoing = NetworkErrorHandler.HandleError(response.StatusCode);
                    Debug.LogError("Request Failed![" + response.StatusCode + "]" + response.Message);

                    if (keepGoing)
                    {
                        ServerManager.NetworkResponse resp = ServerManager.NetworkResponse.Fail;
                        resp.errorcode = response.StatusCode;
                        Debug.LogError("Request Failed![" + response.StatusCode + "]" + response.Message);
                        callback?.Invoke(resp as ReportRequest);
                    }
                }
            });
            Debug.Log("Reached code in GetCompanyReport Block 4");
            request.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500);
            Debug.Log("Reached code in GetCompanyReport Block 5");


            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var data = new BaseNetworkRequestData().SetPincode(CurrentCompany.publicdata.pincode).SetUserData().SetPincode();
            string jsondata = JsonUtility.ToJson(data);
            request.RawData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsondata);
            Debug.Log(jsondata);
            request.Send();
        }
    });
}




whats the response code?  is there a reason you picked httpclient over unitywebrequest?
